# ServiceNow Scheduling for second tuesday of the month

Tags: scripting, scheduling, servicenow

Our company recently switched ticketing systems from ConnectWise to ServiceNow, and the scheduling in servicenow is not near as robust as it was in Connectwise. In connect wise you were able to schedule for the second tuesday of every month and things like that, but there is no such option in ServiceNow. The only thing servicenow has is a script box for putting in conditional statements. Does anyone have any experience with this? I cannot find much documentation about it online.

Answer (score 1):

A user on reddit u/Beer-Me answered the question for me and the results worked.

> When working with Scheduled Jobs, placing this in the condition field should trigger on the first Tuesday of each month.

```
new Date().getDay() == 2 && new Date().getDate() <=7
```

> If you wanted to change it to maybe the 2nd Friday (or whatever), you
>   could do something like this

```
new Date().getDay() == 5 && (new Date().getDate() >7 && new Date().getDate() <= 14)
```

> Got this info from this post on the Community forums Haven't tested
>   this, but it should work.